# Track & store checked status of multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, cookies, checkbox

Hope you're well! I'm still working on this to-do list site and I'm a little stuck for the best way to track if one of the items has been marked as done, and then how to update the cookie that stores the to-do to only load a checked checkbox.

I've seen things like unload and onbeforeunload which seem like a possible way to go, checking through each checkbox on a page unload then storing the status in the cookie for next time the user visits the page.

But I'm wondering if there are any other suggestions? W3schools thinks onunload doesn't work in Opera or Chome (shockingly!) which would be a definite no-go if that is the case.

Thanks guys!

Oh, [link to the site](http://todo.lukeseager.com) if you want to have a mooche around. This is a vanilla JavaScript project, just as an FYI :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not fire something on either `click` or `change` or maybe even `blur` on the checkbox?

If I were doing that I'd probably use localStorage instead of cookies – unless I had to relay the data to the server somehow. (Even then, I'd use localStorage, then AJAX post the contents to the server).

To clarify a bit more, rather than a cookie for each entry (that is going to cause problems with size the way you are doing it), I'd use something like:

```
var checklist = []; // Make an array
```

When a checkbox is clicked, get the words etc then

```
checklist.push({'title': 'Eat some carrots', 'description': 'Orange ones', 'Urgent': 0});
```

or

```
checklist.push({'title': 'Eat some cheese', 'description': 'Cheddar - I hate brie', 'Urgent': 1});
```

Then to display, loop through your checklist array to draw to the screen (however you are doing it already I guess)

When you want to save this array of objects use:

```
localStorage.checklist = JSON.stringify(checklist); // Now our checklist from above is stored in a variable in localStorage called checklist.
```

and to read it back:

```
checklist = localStorage.checklist;
```

If you really needed this on the server you can post checklist there, but you probably don't.
This could now have an app cache (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) added and it would work offline as well. :)

Comment: Aaah, that's a nice thought. An onchange function that updates the cookie, seems much simpler!

Comment: By the way, onunload isn't supported anymore because people kept using it to fire alerts to try to stop people leaving a page! Also, I'd seriously look at localStorage – cookies get sent with every request, so if a user had 100 checkboxes, you might find that you are sending quite a lot of data back and forth on every req.

Comment: Hmm, Ideas on how to change the specific cookie each checkbox belongs to?

Yea I would probably agree with you that localStorage would be a better way to go (unfortunately I didn't know about this until a few days ago). I will probably swap it over at some point. For now though I just want to get a working copy of the site up :)